# Errors running qmake && make

Tags: qt, makefile, gnu-make, qmake, svn2git

I am trying to install svn2git on Windows. At the moment, I have svn2git cloned repo in my C:/ directory. Qt4 (this is the version specified in the manual) is needed to build the However, I have problems installing Qt4 correctly it seems.

Currently, when I try and and rune qmake && make in svn2git folder, I get the following output:

```
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/sh.exe": -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
Makefile:31: recipe for target 'src\Makefile' failed
mingw32-make: *** [src\Makefile] Error 258
```

When I build configure Qt, I have been doing so with:

```
configure -platform win32-msvc2013
```

Not entirely sure which platform I should be installing it with.

And at the end of the configuration output I get:

```
Creating qmake...
execute: File or path is not found (nmake)
execute: File or path is not found (nmake)
Cleaning qmake failed, return code -1
```

I have MinGW installed in C:/ with `mingw32-make.exe` in the bin.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWsWG.png]

Finally, I also have Qt and MinGW in my system environment variables [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaRC5.png]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend simply installing Cygwin, there you have ready-made qt4 packages in the package manager that you simply can install and then building `svn2git` is as easy as calling `qmake-qt4 && make` after you have installed the needed dependencies also through the package manager. At least that is how I build `svn2git` on Windows.

Comment: Hi Vampire, this is a great suggestion. I have uninstalled Qt and now have Cygwin. I have installed everything for make.exe and qmake-qt4, but, I don't have a qmake-qt4.exe, only `x86_64-w64-mingw32-qmake-qt4`  and `x86 -w64-mingw32-qmake-qt4` system files. Could you please shed some light on this? I'm going to try a complete reinstall

Comment: You don't need a `qmake-qt4.exe`. If you open a Cygwin Bash you can simpy run `qmake-qt4` if you have the package installed. There is `/usr/bin/qmake-qt4` then which is a symlink to `/usr/lib/qt4/bin/qmake.exe`. As `/usr/bin` is part of the `PATH` variable you can just use `qmake-qt4` anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I see I have a `/usr/lib/qt4/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin` directory with qmake.exe in it. Also, like you said I have `/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-qmake-qt4`, so I think all is set up correctly. When I am in the svn2git project folder, I get the following error: `QMAKESPEC has not been set, so configuration cannot be deduced.
Error processing project file: /cygdrive/c/<User>/desktop/svn2git/svn2git/fast-export2.pro`.

When I run: `x86_64-w64-mingw32-qmake-qt4 -query`, I get the following output: https://i.imgur.com/2A4BzHS.png

Comment: Maybe you don't have all requirements listed on https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git installed? I cannot remember having seen this error before.

Comment: Even if I'm on Windows I have to install all the `sudo apt-get install build-essential subversion git qtchooser qt5-default libapr1 libapr1-dev libsvn-dev`? Or do I also need Qt installed at the same time? I uninstalled it because I didn't think I needed Qt and Cygwin.

Also, I can't find the package libsvn-dev for Windows. Is it one of these? https://packages.debian.org/sid/libsvn-dev

Comment: If you are on Cygwin you don't use `apt-get`, that's just an example for Debian-based systems. You use the Cygwin package installer GUI instead. There the packages might be called a little bit differently, but you should find them. And yes, of course you need Qt, the one from the Cygwin package manager.

Comment: Btw. alternatively you could also install VirtualBox run Ubuntu in there and then use `apt-get` to install all dependencies, compile and run `svn2git`. Just to mention it.

Comment: I know its a big ask, but, is there any way you could give me a dummy guide to installing it please svn2git on windows please. Having a lot of trouble. I have a 64 bit Windows system. Please let me know if this is feasible.

Comment: As I said, install Cygwin, install in the Cygwin package manager the dependencies listed on the projects page, run the build command.

Answer (score 0):

After installing following packages in cygwin

- make
- automake
- gcc-c++
- subversion
- subversion-devel
- git
- libQt5Core-devel
- libapr1
- libapr1-dev

and creating this symbolic link in the bash

```
ln -s /usr/bin/qmake-qt5 /usr/bin/qmake
```

`qmake && make` worked like a charm and `svn-all-fast-export.exe` was built.